# Suppress "Frequency" text in PROC FREQ

Tags: sas, output

How can I get rid of the box inside the red circle

[image]

code:

```
data mydata;
input x y;
datalines;
    1 2
    3 4
    1 5
    3 2
;
run;

proc freq data=mydata;
    tables x*y /nopercent norow nocol;
run;
```

Comment: Although you already have several answers below, I'd like to suggest using PROC TABULATE instead. You have better control over the output, including column/row headings and formats of variables.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always with SAS there are multiple paths to the desirred result.

If you are willing to step away from `proc freq` you can achieve the required output using `proc tabulate`. This provides a simpler (and more concise) solution and does not require digging through the long and often confusing `proc template` documents.

```
proc tabulate data = mydata;
    /* Specify the variables to investigate */
    class x y; 
    table
        /* Put x in the rows suppress its title and add a total row */
        x = "" all = "Total", 
        /* Put y in the columns, request a total, request frequency count*/
        (y all = "Total") * n = "" / 
            /* Put "x" in the top left box */
            box = "x" 
            /* Put 0 instead of missing */
            misstext = "0"; 
run;
```

Comment: This is actually very useful and probably the best way to go! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
data mydata;
input x y;
datalines;
    1 2
    3 4
    1 5
    3 2
;
run;

/*Write new template to work folder */
ods path work.templat(update) sashelp.tmplmst(read);

/*Remove the "Frequency" header from the template */
proc template;
  edit Base.Freq.CrossTabFreqs;
    edit frequency;
      header="";
    end;
  end;
run;

proc freq data=mydata;
    tables x*y /nopercent norow nocol;
run;
```

Comment: This is a somewhat simpler version of my answer, but I would take issue with editing the base template.  Don't.  Create a template in work so you don't risk messing up the permanent template.  If you simply add the `ods path` statement I suggest, this will work that way (and then you don't need the restore code, since it will disappear when you close SAS).

Comment: Well, my code can't mess up the permanent template in sashelp.tmplmst because sashelp.tmplmst is read-only. My code creates a custom template in sasuser.templat. If anything, I should have just deleted the custom template rather than editing it again to match the default. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're assuming the user doesn't already have a copy in sasuser.templat, though, which isn't necessarily safe.  That's why whenever I do things like this (ie, a truly temporary template) I use work, not sasuser.  I've accidentally left things in sasuser that then have ramifications in future sessions.

Comment: Thanks! This answer works for me when I add the ods path statement in the beginning as Joe suggested. Without that it gives "ERROR: Template 'Base.Freq.CrossTabFreqs' was unable to write to template store!". I don't know if this is because I have multiple SAS systems open and only one of them can use SASUSER.
@DWal maybe you could edit Joe's suggestion about saving the template to work to your answer so people won't have to dig through comments.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this is to edit the `PROC FREQ` template.  Since 9.3 or so, `PROC FREQ` has been rewritten as a basic table via `PROC TEMPLATE`, which is nice because it lets us edit nearly all aspects of it.

What I do is right click on the Results tree header in display manager - like so:
[image: Results]

Then select "Templates".  This opens up the template list, which includes all templates you have installed (both style templates and table templates - most of the PROCs have a table template, though msot do not give you as much control as `PROC FREQ` does).

Then navigate to Sashelp.Tmplmst (Which is the major template store for most preinstalled templates), and open up Base, and then Freq.  This gives you a list of table templates that make up `PROC FREQ`.

In your case, you want to open CrossTabFreqs, which is what you're producing (A crosstab).  You could identify this by running `ods trace on;` then running your code; it will tell you in the log what the name of the template it's using is.

Open that and copy the contents of the template browser to the clipboard, then paste in a new window.  We will modify it, save it in a temporary location, and use it.

Add to the top of the program this line:

```
ods path work.templat(update) sashelp.tmplmst(read);
```

This tells SAS two things: first, when we update or write to the template store, do that in `work`; and two, to look in `work` first then in `sashelp` for templates.  This way when we create our new `CrossTabFreqs` template, it will come from `work`.

Now, look in the program for the location where it defines the `Frequency` block.  This is what you want to modify, since this is the instructions for SAS telling it what to print when it is showing frequencies (as opposed to percents or whatnot).  It will read as so:

```
  define Frequency;                                                       
     header = "Frequency";                                                
     format = BEST7.;                                                     
     label = "Frequency Count";                                           
     print;                                                               
     data_format_override;                                                
  end;
```

You want to remove the `header`.  You can do that one of two ways: either remove the header line entirely, or my preferred option, change it to

```
  define Frequency;                                                       
     header = " ";                                                
     format = BEST7.;                                                     
     label = "Frequency Count";                                           
     print;                                                               
     data_format_override;                                                
  end;
```

Then run the entire program (including the `ods path` statement).  Now, when you use `PROC FREQ` in this SAS session, it will have no text in the frequency table header.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me perfectly and good info to know about templates. Sadly, I can't accept all answers. 
     
One thing though: for me when I browse templates I can't find crosstabs from tmplmst but instead it's in tmplbase. I am using SAS 9.4.

Comment: @Pekka That's interesting.  I have both 9.3. and 9.4, and 9.3 it's there; 9.4 matches what you see.  I didn't realize they moved it!